# Find Polar Differential Equation that satisfies Bifurcation Diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

This is my first time using MathStackExchange, so let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. I'm struggling to solve this question: Find a polar differential equation (i.e. $$\frac{dr}{dt}=f(r, \alpha)$$ such that it satisfies the bifurcation diagram linked: [Bifurcation Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFRNE.png)

[image: bifurcation diagram]

I guess it isn't strictly polar, just that the variable is confined to $\geq 0$. I've played around with some powers of $r$ in the function, but am unable to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not really clear where the equilibrium point is unstable. Could you be more precise in the picture? E.g. use different colours.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to study the different types of [local bifurcations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_theory#Local_bifurcations) (in one parameter), all of which can be described by their [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form_(dynamical_systems)). The bifurcation diagram in your question corresponds to one (maybe more?) of these local bifurcations, and the functional expression $f(r,\alpha)$ that gives rise to this is given by the corresponding normal form. Note that you may have to combine several local bifurcations to construct the bifurcation diagram from your question.